# In Thrift, is there a way to avoid generating C++ setters?

Tags: c++, thrift

When I use this .thrift file

```
struct Character {
  1: required string firstname;
  2: required string lastname;
  3: required string nickname;
}
```

and compile it with `--gen cpp:no_default_operators,no_skeleton` I get:

```
class Character : public virtual ::apache::thrift::TBase {
 public:

  Character(const Character&);
  Character& operator=(const Character&);
  Character() : firstname(), lastname(), nickname() {
  }

  virtual ~Character() throw();
  std::string firstname;
  std::string lastname;
  std::string nickname;

  void __set_firstname(const std::string& val);

  void __set_lastname(const std::string& val);

  void __set_nickname(const std::string& val);

  uint32_t read(::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* iprot);
  uint32_t write(::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* oprot) const;

  virtual void printTo(std::ostream& out) const;
};

void swap(Character &a, Character &b);

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Character& obj);
```

For the sake of compactness, is there a way I could avoid having the setters generated?

Using Thrift version 0.11.0

Comment: why? Do they affect anything?

Comment: As I said, it is just for the sake of compactness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible with the Thrift compiler. If you look at the code, you can see that the declarations of the setters are generated by this code ([link](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/0acf23b7cf39922a2eee9b969e4e73989050f0d6/compiler/cpp/src/thrift/generate/t_cpp_generator.cc#L1192)):

```
  // Create a setter function for each field
  for (m_iter = members.begin(); m_iter != members.end(); ++m_iter) {
    if (pointers) {
      continue;
    }
    if (is_reference((*m_iter))) {
      out << endl << indent() << "void __set_" << (*m_iter)->get_name() << "(::std::shared_ptr<"
          << type_name((*m_iter)->get_type(), false, false) << ">";
      out << " val);" << endl;
    } else {
      out << endl << indent() << "void __set_" << (*m_iter)->get_name() << "("
          << type_name((*m_iter)->get_type(), false, true);
      out << " val);" << endl;
    }
  }
```

This code is contained in the following function:

```
void t_cpp_generator::generate_struct_declaration(ostream& out,
                                                  t_struct* tstruct,
                                                  bool is_exception,
                                                  bool pointers,
                                                  bool read,
                                                  bool write,
                                                  bool swap,
                                                  bool is_user_struct)
```

Likewise, the definition of the setters is generated by this function ([link](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/0acf23b7cf39922a2eee9b969e4e73989050f0d6/compiler/cpp/src/thrift/generate/t_cpp_generator.cc#L1298)), with the `setters` parameter controlling whether the setter function should be generated:

```
void t_cpp_generator::generate_struct_definition(ostream& out,
                                                 ostream& force_cpp_out,
                                                 t_struct* tstruct,
                                                 bool setters,
                                                 bool is_user_struct)
```

Both of these functions are called here ([link](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/0acf23b7cf39922a2eee9b969e4e73989050f0d6/compiler/cpp/src/thrift/generate/t_cpp_generator.cc#L897)):

```
void t_cpp_generator::generate_cpp_struct(t_struct* tstruct, bool is_exception) {
  generate_struct_declaration(f_types_, tstruct, is_exception, false, true, true, true, true);
  generate_struct_definition(f_types_impl_, f_types_impl_, tstruct, true, true);
```

As you can see, the `pointers` parameter for `generate_struct_declaration` is hard-coded to `false` and the `setters` parameter for `generate_struct_definition` is hard-coded to `true`. So there currently is no option for by-passing the generation of these functions.